# HeadersAlready sent error when using TCPDF with Yii2

Tags: yii2, tcpdf

I am getting HeadersAlreadySent Exception whenever I am printing PDF using TCPDF library, tried following suggestions found on other similar kind of questions, but in vain, none has worked

```
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();// All other content            
return $pdf->Output($localFilePath, $destination);
```

Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is non fatal error though, PDF is getting printed without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, go to the file called as "tcpdf_static.php" from the tcpdf vendor folder, and in function sendOutputData, replace echo $data with following lines to resolve the issue

```
ob_start();        
ob_end_clean();// All other content        
echo $data;
ob_end_flush();
die;
```